# Azure AD B2C - registration flow with an update feature (custom policy)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using B2C flow to manage registrations on a site,

we have a set of users already created in AD B2C (with some fields missing, like email, ...)

Does it possible to use a registration flow B2C with a custom policy to update existing record in AD B2C rather then create new one in some cases, (during a registration process  perform a matching check, current user to register to existing ones in AD B2C, if matched - update field missing fields)

**update**
some new users are coming from a special link, so we are know their AD B2C userid, and matching will be by it

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible depending on how you plan to match up user records. Please update your question to include how you plan to match a registering user to a pre-existing b2c user

Comment: Have updated the question